# Piecewise function and integral function

Tags: piecewise

Given a piecewise function `f[t_]:=Piecewise[{{Exp[-1/t^2],t>0},{0,x<=0}}]`, I can define another function like this: `g[t_]:=f[t+1]f[1-t]`. Both the functions can be calculated and plotted. But when I define the third function `h[t_]:=Integrate[g[x],{x,-:inf:,t}]`, `h[t]` cannot be used to plot. Does the definition for `h[t]` have anything wrong?

Comment: Please be more specific about what you mean by "cannot be used".  Also: did you mean to write `x <= 0` or `t <= 0` in `f`?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Recommend that the definition of `g` be modified to `g[t_] = f[t + 1] f[1 - t] // PiecewiseExpand // Simplify`

Comment: Thanks, I have revised the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error in the definition of `f[]` and it's faster to use `NIntegrate[]`:

```
f[t_] := Piecewise[{{Exp[-1/t^2], t > 0}, {0, t <= 0}}]
g[t_] := f[t + 1] f[1 - t]
h[t_] := NIntegrate[g[x], {x, -Infinity, t}]
Plot[h[t], {t, -1, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]